# Shall I use have forgotten or forget in this sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

First, thank you userr2684291 for reminding me of the web site's name.

Here is the situation:
I couldn't remember the name of LXXX-8 web site, so I went to the chatroom to get some help. (I don't know whether advertisement is allowed here or not, so I put XXX in the web site's name)

> Could you remind me the web site's name please?
>   It is a web site that you can write some sentences, and some other users will come to help
>   you check your grammar.
>   ColleenV once told me the web site's name, but
>   **I have forgotten**

I felt like using simple present tense in the last sentence, but
my hands was typing the sentence in present perfect tense.

I think simple present tense is also correct, but I don't know how to explain it to myself that which one is the better.

> ColleenV once told me the web site's name, but **I forget it now**

I am sorry, moderators.
I have read the suggested answer in the given link, but
I do not understand how it can help me solve my question.
I would like to know which of the tenses is the better in the given situation.

I need help.
And which one sounds more natural to your native ears?

> "I have forgotten" or "I forget it now"

Comment: Sadly, your question has been marked as a dupe of a question that asks something different; but FWIW, the answer is in the first definition at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forget, which shows that *forget* has two intimately-related senses: one that allows your version with "I have forgotten", and implies that you no longer remember the name, and one that allows your version with "I forget", and implies merely that you can't recall the name right now (but leaves open the possibility that you'll remember it later).

Comment: The present perfect always casts the statement about a past event in terms of the present, so that **I've forgotten her name** would mean that "at this moment I am unable to tell you her name -- it was not in my head when I last checked" (which could be just a second ago or a month ago). The present perfect merely establishes the *point before which* the action took place. The simple present, **I forget her name** means "at this moment her name is not coming to mind". If you have been asking here and there for the name, you might well say *I've forgotten*, whereas  *I forget* is spontaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I forget it **now**

...talks about that 'very moment'.

> ... I **have forgotten**

... the use of past participle makes it the 'process' starting from that point till now.

For *a non-native speaker* like me, the simpler version is...

> ColleenV once told me the web site's name [sic] **that I don't remember**.